# IP packet traveling back to the client

Tags: networking, ip

I know we have MAC addresses and IP addresses which are on the different layers.

MAC addresses are for the communication between nodes (switch) and IP addresses - for networks (router)

Mac addresses are changed during a packet sending but ip addresses are not

Let's suppose my ip is 192.168.1.10 (from my local network)
We send a request to a public ip, suppose it's 10.98.9.3

1. We send an ip packet to a server (source_ip - 192.168.1.10, destination_ip - 10.98.9.3)
2. It goes to a switch, then to a router and then trough a chain of several routers to a different network and to the device with destination_ip 10.98.9.3.
3. Then the server should response me, using source_ip as destination_ip now. But 192.168.1.10 is an ip form my local network. How does server know where to send packets back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your private IP (`192.168.1.10`) server won't see, because you are behind a NAT (especially PAT), your private IP is translated to some public IP, which was assigned to you by your ISP. When returning back a packet, this remote server will send it to your NAT and this NAT will translate it to your private IP :) That's all. NAT is the answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all, both 192.168.1.x and 10.98.9.x are private, non-routable (over the public Internet) IP addresses. So your example will work only as long as you control the routers and have created the necessary routes, or in certain other circumstances.

Also, if you do run this over the Internet, IP addresses would get translated using a mechanism known as NAT. That introduces complexities I'll ignore for the same of the answer.

For the sake of the answer, I will simply pretend that both source and destination IP addresses are connected and routable to each other.

Now to answer the questions, it really helps to separate the layers here. IP packets are on layer 3, and I'll consider this first.

## Layer 3

The IP packet contains both the source and the destination address. The packet you send says "I am going to 10.98.9.3 and I am coming from 192.168.1.10".

Once the computer at the far end of the connection receives this packet and is ready to respond, it will simply reverse these two: "I am going to 192.168.1.10 and I am coming from 10.98.9.3".

## Routing

Now the next question is how your computer knows how to send a packet to 10.98.9.3. The answer is: it doesn't. But it knows somebody else (known as the default gateway) who does.

Your computer on 192.168.1.10 will first check if the destination is on the same subnet, or on a different subnet. To do that, it uses the subnet mask. For instance, if the subnet mask is 255.255.255.0, then your computer will check if the source and destination have the same three numbers in common.

If the destination was on the same subnet (for instance, 192.168.1.27), then your computer could send the packet directly to the destination. In your example, the destination is on a different subnet.

To find out if a computer is on the same or a different subnet, it uses the subnet mask.

Your computer contains a table, called a routing table, that describes how to get to other networks. It looks something like this (on a Linux computer, Windows is similar)

```
Kernel IP routing table                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface                                                                                                                                                          
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens192                                                                                                                                                         
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens192
```

The first entry says that packets to anywhere (destination 0.0.0.0 and genmask 0.0.0.0) have to be sent to 192.168.1.1, which is the router who knows how to get the packet to the destination.

The second entry is essentially an exception to the first rule. It says that anything that starts with 192.168.1 (the genmask, or subnet mask, 255.255.255.0 describes how many bits of the IP address are considered here) goes directly (gateway 0.0.0.0) to the destination. It also says that it should use the interface (NIC) called ens192 to connect to 192.168.1.1.

So for 10.98.9.3, your computer will use the first rule, find that these packets should instead go to 192.168.1.1. Then your computer uses the same table a second time, and finds that 192.168.1.1 can be sent directly via the interface ens192.

The same thing happens on the opposite side with the response.

All of this happens within your own network; the destination has no idea of all of this.

## Layer 2 - MAC addresses.

Note that the mac addresses really have nothing to do with any of this. They come into play to deal with one aspect I glossed over earlier: within your own network, how does your computer actually send a packet either directly to the destination computer, or to the default gateway, or whatever else the routing table says.

Once your computer figured out that the packet should be sent to 192.168.1.1 (the default gateway), or 192.168.1.27 (a directly reachable computer), or whatever else it is, your computer will send out a request for a MAC address using the ARP protocol: "who is 192.168.1.27?" That computer will then respond with "I am 192.168.1.27, and my MAC address is 00:11:22:33:44:55"

Then your computer will wrap (encapsulate) your packet into an Ethernet frame with that MAC address as destination (and your own MAC address as the source).